# How to transform dictionary into dataframe in a specific way in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

My dictionary looks like below:

[image]

So the keys are userIDs, and the values are contents. I want to change them into dataframe but in my specific way. The way I want is, as below:

[image]

In summary, I would like all individual values to be rows matching with the key (userId)

So userId is broadcasted from the first value of the key to the end and then recursively do the job until the last userId.
I wish to know how to do it in code in python.

That would be much help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need change dictionary to list of tuples and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
d = {'a':[1,2,4], 'b':[4,6,7]}

df = pd.DataFrame([(k, x) for k, v in d.items() for x in v], columns=['user','content'])
print (df)
  user  content
0    a        1
1    a        2
2    a        4
3    b        4
4    b        6
5    b        7
```